# AES-256 best practices implementation

Tags: encryption, aes

I'm reversing an app but I'm not very expert of the **AES algorithm**.
The application gives the user the opportunity to make an offline login.

The user is asked to provide his ***username*** and ***password***

This is the function that is used to store the info of the user

```
    public void EncryptLoginInfo(string username, byte[] secretShared, byte[] salt)
{
  byte[] random = calc.GenerateRandomBytes();
  byte[] array = aes.Encrypt(secretShared, random);
  OfflineLogin loginInfo = new OfflineLogin()
  {
    Username = username,
    SecretShared = array,
    Iv = random,
    Salt = salt
  };
  this._userCredentials.StoreOfflineLoginData(username, loginInfo);
}
```

And this are the info that are stored inside an internal config file of the app. In the example below, the **password** passed to the **encryptLoginInfo** is **123**

```
Username: not_important
SecretShared: 4KVrjy1cQVWYpWF7aolpMS0HzhKyFf+9VXauQrXoXVUbf0bGXIDOLDJuSVhYoFo2
Iv:yil4nn02IoKsOnX5KXVsDg==
Salt: 5kJio2VQEqjomHRdQMqRVJ0zkBsmqi8K3NypC2VWJk4
```

If the user want to make an offline login, he is asked to provide username and his password.

**Question**: Is this algo safe? If an attacker is able to obtain SecretShared+Iv+Salt is he able to recover the password of the user (that in this specific example is **123**)

This is the decrypt function

```
public void DencryptLoginInfo(OfflineLogin loginInfo)
{
  byte[] array = aes.Decrypt(loginInfo.SecretShared, loginInfo.Iv);
  loginInfo.SecretShared = array;
  loginInfo.Iv = (byte[]) null;
}
```

Are you able to spot any security issues in this implementation? **The algo used should be AES-256.**. Are you able to implement a POC in python to decrypt the PASSWORD given SecretShared+Iv+Salt?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you authenticating users by encrypting *something* or are you actually encrypting useful data using the password of a user? Keep in mind that Stack Overflow deals with questions related to programming which your question doesn't fit.

Comment: Authenticate the user by encrypting his password

Comment: @paolino You should not be encrypting his password, instead you should be hashing it with a password based key derivation function.  Alright, please fix up your question and then I can fix up my answer.

Comment: Hi! I updated the question with all the info required. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, your goal is to authenticate the user.  For that we use password base key derivation functions on the password.  Often people refer to this as "hashing passwords", which is unfortunate terminology because "hashing" can mean anything.  But the main point is that we do not encrypt passwords, instead we send them through a one-way function that is designed to be slow.  The slow speed deters brute force attacks.

You do not need an IV to do this.  Instead, your app should be deriving a salt and and using a password based key derivation function (sometimes referred to as a "password hashing" algorithm: you will have to excuse that the industry has made a mess out of the terminology on this topic).  You can find guidance on this all over the web.  But I suggest you have a read of [point 4 in Top 10 Developer Crypto Mistakes](https://littlemaninmyhead.wordpress.com/2017/04/22/top-10-developer-crypto-mistakes/) to see common pitfalls in implementing this.

Don't use openssl to convert a password into a key (or password hash)!  The algorithm in openssl is [weak](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29139/78214).  Openssl's EVP_BytesToKey() fails to meet the requirements of slow speed, meaning that it is easy to brute force your key from your password.

The proper solution to this problem is to use an algorithm such as bcrypt or pbkdf2 (Java implementations can be found without much effort) to derive a "hash" from the password.  You then verify that the user typed in the password correctly by re-doing the same computation with the user entered password and the salt that was stored for this password.  If they match, access is granted, otherwise access is denied.

Note that if this app interacts with a server, normally you do password verification on the server side.  If your app does not interact with a server, then you may have a good reason to do it on the device.  I don't know what your app does, so I cannot tell you what is right or wrong for you.

A great reference for doing this properly is [How to Safely Store Your Users' Passwords in 2016](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016) .

Comment: Hi greatContini! I updated the question with all the info required. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @paolino What is the relation of the secretShared to the password?  I'm also not clear on the API for aes.Decrypt( ).  It looks like secretShared is being decrypted, but I am not clear what key is being used, nor am I clear on the mode of operation.  More info is needed to answer this.

Comment: secretShared to the password? :) That's the question I'm trying to answer :). And these are all the details extracted from the client. Many thanks for your help

Comment: I can attempt to answer a question about code, but I cannot make guesses about code that is missing.